# Auth Error while calling BigQueryV2 API through a service account

Tags: python-3.x, api, authentication, google-bigquery

I would like to call [BigQuery's V2 jobs.get](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/bigquery_v2.jobs.html#get) API with python and a service account.

For development purpose I've create a service account with Owner + BigQuery Admin permissions and downloaded the file locally. The scopes for the calls were retrieved by the [API explorer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get)'s site.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account

job_id = "df976258-aa9c-4fd1-ae8d-7604abc6d6e7"
key_path = "/path/to/sa/file/sa-key-file.json"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_path)
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.readonly'
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only'])


service = build('bigquery', 'v2', credentials=scoped_credentials)
```

Debugging this code locally leads me to an invalid authorisation:

```
service._http.credentials.valid        # returns False
```

**Follow up question:**

Assuming the authentication works, how do I need to call the jobs.get method? I tried several combinations but get always an error:

```
service.jobs().get()                   # {TypeError}Missing required parameter "jobId"
service.jobs().get(project-id, job_id) # {TypeError}method() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
service.jobs(job_id).get(project-id)   # {TypeError}methodResource() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
service.jobs(project_id).get(job_id)   # {TypeError}methodResource() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
service.jobs().get(job_id)             # {TypeError}methodResource() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Do you consider to use google.cloud.bigquery python library to [Managing Jobs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/jobs.html)

Comment: Yeah I did. Unfortunately it is not possible to get detailed job information, like in the Api call above, in the client library. Or at least I haven't found anything

Comment: Just my gut feeling that it might help to check source code of python library on GitHub because I think (but I might be wrong) it is just a wrapper around the rest api.

Comment: Yeah it is a wrapper - but it seems that there isn't a 1:1 feature mirror.